# ffmpeg remove Non-Monotonous DTS frames

Tags: ffmpeg, dts

Is it possible to stream copy a .ts file to another .ts file by removing the Non-Monotonous DTS frames? These frames usually also have a smaller resolution than the video I am trying to copy. I attempted this with VideoReDo but it did not work and I cannot seem to make it work.

Also, the MediaInfo for the video after remixed to Matrosks shows this:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames               : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 2 h 35 min
Nominal bit rate                         : 6 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 896 pixels
Original width                           : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 504 pixels
Original height                          : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Original frame rate                      : 60.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.443
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2579M 73ae2d1
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=4 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=250 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / stitchable=1 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=122 / keyint_min=12 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=10 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=6000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=5 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When streamcopying, you can't just drop any frames from the middle of a stream. At best, you can drop entire GOPs.

Comment: @Mulvya I want to drop the GOPs that are certain size of pixels, is there a way to detect them and drop them?

Comment: @MiGu3X do you use a multiplexed TS as input (multiple programs)?

Comment: @aergistal I downloaded a stream which has #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY in the middle (when there are ADS), this disconitunitys seem to throw the Non-Monotonous DTS warning messages and have a smaller frame size (896x504) instead of the original 1280x720. When I try to remove this frames, almost every program crash, I tried TSDoctor, VideoReDo, mpeg2repair and none of them seem to fix the issue. I want to remove this smaller frames from the original ts stream.

Comment: @MiGu3X the ad sequences will start with a timestamp near 0 (hence the Non-Monotonous DTS message) and end when the original stream resumes (another discontinuity). You can use this information to filter out the TS packets that are out of the initial timestamp range. I don't know any program that does that automatically but it's relatively easy to program.

Comment: Okay, but I'm using VLC to capture the video stream since it doesn't need any aditional headers, do you have any idea with what tool/plugin I can program it and which language? I can capture the streams also on ffmpeg but the video overlaps and it appears to show as if it is 6hrs long and eventually fucks all up...

Comment: Also, the timestamps aren't near 0, they are the same as the regular frames, the only difference is that discontinuities are inside #EXT-X-DISCONTIUNITY, if in some way I can sort the .ts files and remove those that are inside those tags, then maybe I could fix the issue.

Comment: @MiGu3X I'm talking about the timestamps in the elementary streams. You would need a parser. If you can re-download it's easier: download all the individual segments (scripted not VLC), filter out the ads based on `ffprobe` output and concatenate the remaining ones in a single `.ts` file then remux it to some other format like `mp4` etc.

Comment: And how am I able to download the segments individually? Ffmpeg doesn't have that feature right? And doing it manually by downloading the m3u8 file is impossible because the stream already happened..

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix the videofile by ripping video and audio streams and then re-assembling them again as is suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/605818/ffmpeg-non-monotonous-dts):

```
ffmpeg -i op.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.11 -t 00:00:06.00 -vn -y op.wav
ffmpeg -i op.mp4 -ss 0.010000 -t 00:00:06 -vcodec rawvideo -an -y op.avi
ffmpeg -i op.avi -i op.wav -b:v 590k -b:a 130k -t 00:00:06 -y op_fixed.mp4
```

Comment: By doing it that way I have to, for each discontinuity, check exactly which frame/milisecond I have to cut with some program, there are a lot of discontinuities in the middle of the files (2 hrs video with approximately 20 discontinuites). I don't think this is a solution